How can I generate Prisma CUID's when using sql?
I have a Prisma ORM server for my database. I am trying to use the cuid() function outside of the prisma schema.prisma file, but I don't see any package that imports that function and I don't know where it comes from. I want change the format of a table and I'm in the process of migrating the data from one format to another by making different tables (one with the original data and one with the newly formatted data). Currently, I use an approach using prisma queries to get the data I need, but I want to try using SQL queries to both fetch and create the new rows in the new format table and test which approach is faster. Currently my prisma approach is quite slow, it will take about a 2.5 months to migrate the data at my current pace.
How can I use the same cuid() function that prisma uses in its schema.prisma on a javascript file?
My database uses PostgreSQL.
I've tried calling the cuid() function but it shows up as not installed. I have been doing research on the cuid() packages for npm but I'm not sure if they are the same as the one Prisma uses. I would only use the package to create the ID's of all the migrated data, as any new data would be generated directly with the prisma create function.
I want something similar to this:
query = `INSERT INTO new_format_table(id, attr1, attr2, attr3)
VALUES(${cuid()}, val1, val2, val3)`


As per Prisma's documentation, cuid is 'implemented by Prisma ORM and therefore not "visible" in the underlying database schema'. Prisma doesn't tell how they implement it, but by all logic, cuid2 library should be compatible.
Prisma's cuid's are stored as VARCHAR(30) (you should be able to verify this from your underlying DB).
To generate cuid ID's in code, see the repo's documentation. In short, it's very straight-forward:
npm install --save @paralleldrive/cuid2

and:
import { createId } from '@paralleldrive/cuid2';
const id = createId();

